# Transfer of Questions to Other Sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

From time to time [questions](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23583) come up that clearly would better fit to other sites. As of now, the procedure of

```
-> CLOSE
   -> COMMUNITY REASON
      -> OTHER SITE
```

only allows the selection of Meta, as standard for beta sties. AFAIK [graduating enables](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/678/6659) moderators to add other targets.

- Is that true?
- Can it already be done?

If yes to both, I think it would be a good idea to collect a list of targets (*1). Personally I think

- Main [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) - for generic Programming questions
- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - for *basic* Hardware related questions
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) - for Arcade related questions

should be added to that list. Meta may need to stay (as last option) for cases needing moderation.

Looking at [The Stats](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) (Thanks for the reminder to Stephen) show a few several migrations

Questions were migrated to

- 6 to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)
- 5 to Electrical Engineering
- 4 to [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- 2 to [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
- 2 to Arqade

an one to each of [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/32876/what-do-i-need-to-know-about-buying-a-vcr-for-digitising-old-vhs-tapes), the main SO, [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/26547/why-did-microsoft-not-have-to-publish-the-protocol-for-skype) and [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49738/custom-leds-from-raspberry-pi-3-with-retropie-build) (*1). So at least **Unix**, **SU** and **CS** would further make wortwhile candidates.

- Any other to be added?

---

*1 - I understand this list as a helper to users suggesting migration, so moderators doing this get an suggestion where to it should go.

*2 - Not many, which makes me wonder if our readers are that well verses in making only on topic questions or if we're hesitating too much to move border on topic ones.

Comment: I don't see a tool for it, but I know it _can_ be done; I think we have to ask specifically for a migration path (so posting a question here is the correct first step).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limited migration choices for moving off-topic questions?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/674/limited-migration-choices-for-moving-off-topic-questions)

Comment: @user3840170 When reading both question in full, it's obvious that the one you're reffering does describe the situation in Beta, which may change due [graduation](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/were-graduating), as Whizzwizz4 mentioned as prerequisite in his [Answer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/678/6659) to the very same question you cite. Isn't it?

Comment: If nothing else, it might help to keep the questions linked. But the other question is still accepting answers, so one might as well propose migration paths there.

Comment: @user3840170 That doesn't make much sense. My basic question is if it now can be done. Also, every question does accept answers. Turning questions into moving targets is never a good idea. New situation, new direction -> new question!

Comment: Sometimes it’s a very good idea. Meta threads are often linked to as justifications for policy decisions, and it’s helpful if they reflect current community consensus, not just one of the time. But I won’t be pressing this matter too much.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true, we can add (and/or edit) both site-specific close reasons and migration targets as we become a graduated site.

Close reason changes require two moderators to agree on the action and click the appropriate buttons.  Migration target changes, as far as I know, have to be made by SE staff upon request.

The answer by user3840170 makes a very good point - do we need them?  Assuming that we do, the targets should be chosen very carefully.  Migration is not something that is done lightly. Before migrating anything under the current system, moderators go through a checklist before clicking the button.  It can be too easy to migrate on a whim.  Look at the arguments on ELU and ELL metas regarding migration between those two sites.  The last thing we want is something similar between us and - for example - Arqade.

I'm not against it, just against haste.

Comment: "It can be too easy to migrate on a whim." This sounds as if a single migrate request from a single user could do so. Is this the case? My impression was that it needs, like closing, a certain number of vote which not only need to agree on migrating, but as well on using the same target. So, what's wrong in trusting the community to self regulate?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with self-regulation. It is the best way.  Migration would need 5 votes.

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think we *need* more automatic migration paths.  According to [our listing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) (as of January 2022), since June 2016 we have only had 37 questions migrated away; that’s barely more than one migrated question per two months.  Of those, 14 (nearly half) were to our own Meta.  The current unofficial system in which community members suggest migration paths to moderators in comments seems just enough to handle a volume this low.

I fear automatic migration paths would mostly serve as a new favourite hammer of knee-jerk close voters to whom everything looks like a nail, e.g. voting off questions to Arqade at the first mention of video games anywhere.  Because I do think we have something of a problem with overzealous closing (see [Question mischaracterized as off-topic](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/), [Why is the question about running Windows 95 in DOSBox supposedly off-topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/), [What was unclear about this question?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1073/)).  I think requiring a moderator intervention in this process could do well to temper this tendency.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good argument turning a technical question (which targets would be useful) into a political (I do not want to give the community the power to self regulate). If you think it need to be discussed, it would be a good idea to open a dedicated question to talk about political handling, as this question is simply about possible targets.

Comment: Like Lessig said, code is law.

Comment: And twisting arguments for political gain never a good idea. Why not try to stay on topic and cooperate?

Comment: I am staying on-topic. Adding more migration targets is just as much a political decision as not doing so. Being in denial about a technical decision having political consequences is not a good idea either.